# H3 geo overlay for Android

Tags: android, h3

Is it possible to draw H3 (https://www.gislounge.com/h3-open-source-geospatial-indexing-system/) geo overlay for android?
Maybe some maps API supporting this layer? I know that for example you can draw any polygon for map - but if there will be a lot of polygons, it will be too slow to draw.
GeoJSON doesn't support transparency for color filling.
If we will use tile overlay - there is rectancle pictures - how to decode H3 hexagons to show it in rectangle pictures?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to answer this question without knowing what map framework you're using, and in any case, the answer is going to be specific to your use case. You can represent H3 as GeoJSON or any other geo format that supports polygons, or you could create image or vector tiles for the H3 data you want to show.

Comment: I want to find any map framework, that supports H3 layer from the box

Comment: @ВладимирФишер there is an API for this. https://posts.gle/V9aC1P it returns GeoJson and you can integrate into Googlemaps,etc.